# Cannot set Session userid.

Tags: php, session

In my login system userid is auto increment when anyone registers. I want to echo the userid of the logged in session. Searching through other answers suggests adding

> $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid

in the login part of the session. echo $userid says undefined variable. Any fix?

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            @$username=$_POST['username'];
            @$password=$_POST['password'];
            $query = "SELECT * from users where username='$username' and password='$password' ";
            //echo $query;
            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            if($query_run)
            {
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;

                header( "Location: profile.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("No such User exists or username and password do not match. Invalid Credentials")</script>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Database Error")</script>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: what is the name of the user id column in the database?

Comment: You don't define `$userid` anywhere in this code, hence the message.

Comment: the column is 'userid' .

Comment: how in anyway this is exact duplicate? -.-

Comment: The column may be `userid`, but that doesn't mean there's magically a **variable** named that. You haven't defined a variable called `$userid` anywhere. There's probably one called `$row['userid']`, though.